# "Occasional" Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, mingw, endianness

Issue is regarding GRIB parser (link to GRIB file https://github.com/Gifciak/GRIB),
As I am executing my code (though codeblocks or on linux through console - `g++ main.cpp -pedantic` ) I am getting an error, segmentation fault but it doesn't always happen.

As for example, while I am compiling 10 times, 8 times there will be an error, and 2 times everything will work fine which will provide me with console output and information.

As I have researched, the issue stands with `std::copy`, as it might be trying to an copy iterator which doesn't exist anymore.

Can someone explain why does it happen?
Why doesn't it always crash or succeed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using ByteVec = std::vector<uint8_t>;


template<typename T, size_t size = sizeof(T)>
auto getReverseEndianValue(const auto & iter) {
    union {
        T result;
        char tmp[size];
    } buffer;

    auto reverseIter = std::make_reverse_iterator(std::next(iter, size));
    std::copy(reverseIter, std::next(reverseIter, size), buffer.tmp);

    return buffer.result;
}

enum Edition {
    Edition_Unknown = -1,
    Edition_GRIB1 = 1,
};

namespace section {
    class IS {
    public:
        uint32_t magicFlag;
        uint32_t size;
        Edition edition;

        static IS read(const auto & iter) {
            IS result;
            result.magicFlag = getReverseEndianValue<uint32_t>(iter);
            result.size = getReverseEndianValue<uint32_t, 3>(iter + 4);
            result.edition = (*(iter + 7) == 1 ? Edition_GRIB1 : Edition_Unknown);
            return result;
        }
    };

    class PDS {
    public:
        uint32_t size;
        uint8_t tableVersion;
        uint8_t indentificatorOfCenter;
        uint8_t numProcessID;
        uint8_t gridIndentification;
        uint8_t flagForGDSorBMS;
        uint8_t indParamAndUnit;
        uint8_t indTypeOfLevelOrLayer;
        uint16_t levelOrLayer;
        uint8_t year;
        uint8_t month;
        uint8_t day;
        uint8_t hour;
        uint8_t minute;
        uint8_t forecastTimeUnit;
        uint8_t p1;
        uint8_t p2;
        uint8_t indTimeRange;
        uint16_t averageOrAccumulate;
        uint8_t missing;
        uint8_t century;
        uint8_t subcenterId;
        uint16_t decimalScale;
        ByteVec data;

        static PDS read(const auto& iter) {
            PDS result;
            result.size = getReverseEndianValue<uint32_t, 3>(iter);
            result.tableVersion = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 3);
            result.indentificatorOfCenter = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 4);
            result.numProcessID = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 5);
            result.gridIndentification = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 6);
            result.flagForGDSorBMS = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 7);
            result.indParamAndUnit = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 8);
            result.indTypeOfLevelOrLayer = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 9);
            result.levelOrLayer = getReverseEndianValue<uint16_t>(iter + 10);
            result.year = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 12);
            result.month = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 13);
            result.day = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 14);
            result.hour = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 15);
            result.minute = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 16);
            result.forecastTimeUnit = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 17);
            result.p1 = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 18);
            result.p2 = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 19);
            result.indTimeRange = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 20);
            result.averageOrAccumulate = getReverseEndianValue<uint16_t>(iter + 21);
            result.missing = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 23);
            result.century = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 24);
            result.subcenterId = getReverseEndianValue<uint8_t>(iter + 25);
            result.decimalScale = getReverseEndianValue<uint16_t>(iter + 26);
            return result;
        }
    };
}

class GribData {
private:
    section::IS secIS;
    section::PDS secPDS;

public:
    void print() {
        std::cout
            << "### Section IS ###\n"
            << "magicFlag: " << +secIS.magicFlag << "\n"
            << "size: " << +secIS.size << "\n"
            << "edition: " << +secIS.edition << "\n"

            << "\n### Section PDS ###\n"
            << "size: " << +secPDS.size << "\n"
            << "tableVersion: " << +secPDS.tableVersion << "\n"
            << "indentificatorOfCenter: " << +secPDS.indentificatorOfCenter << "\n"
            << "numProcessID: " << +secPDS.numProcessID << "\n"
            << "gridIndentification: " << +secPDS.gridIndentification << "\n"
            << "flagForGDSorBMS: " << +secPDS.flagForGDSorBMS << "\n"
            << "indParamAndUnit: " << +secPDS.indParamAndUnit << "\n"
            << "indTypeOfLevelOrLayer: " << +secPDS.indTypeOfLevelOrLayer << "\n"
            << "levelOrLayer: " << +secPDS.levelOrLayer << "\n"
            << "year: " << +secPDS.year << "\n"
            << "month: " << +secPDS.month << "\n"
            << "day: " << +secPDS.day << "\n"
            << "hour: " << +secPDS.hour << "\n"
            << "minute: " << +secPDS.minute << "\n"
            << "forecastTimeUnit: " << +secPDS.forecastTimeUnit << "\n"
            << "p1: " << +secPDS.p1 << "\n"
            << "p2: " << +secPDS.p2 << "\n"
            << "indTimeRange: " << +secPDS.indTimeRange << "\n"
            << "averageOrAccumulate: " << +secPDS.averageOrAccumulate << "\n"
            << "missing: " << +secPDS.missing << "\n"
            << "century: " << +secPDS.century << "\n"
            << "subcenterId: " << +secPDS.subcenterId << "\n"
            << "decimalScale: " << +secPDS.decimalScale << "\n";

    }

    static GribData loadData(const ByteVec& rawdata) {
        GribData result;

        constexpr char MAGIC_START[4] = { 'G', 'R', 'I', 'B' };
        constexpr char MAGIC_END[4] = { '7', '7', '7', '7' };

        auto start = std::search(rawdata.cbegin(),
            rawdata.cend(),
            std::begin(MAGIC_START),
            std::end(MAGIC_START));

        auto end = std::search(rawdata.cbegin(),
            rawdata.cend(),
            std::begin(MAGIC_END),
            std::end(MAGIC_END));

        ByteVec data(start, end + sizeof(MAGIC_END));

        result.secIS = section::IS::read(data.cbegin());
        result.secPDS = section::PDS::read(data.cbegin() + 8);

        auto size = getReverseEndianValue<uint32_t, 3>(data.cbegin() + 4);

        auto sec1 = getReverseEndianValue<uint32_t, 3>(data.cbegin() + 8);
        auto sec2 = getReverseEndianValue<uint32_t, 3>(data.cbegin() + 8 + sec1);
        auto sec3 = getReverseEndianValue<uint32_t, 3>(data.cbegin() + 8 + sec1 + sec2);

        std::cout
            << "size: " << size << "\n"
            << "sec0: " << 8 << "\n"
            << "sec1: " << sec1 << "\n"
            << "sec2: " << sec2 << "\n"
            << "sec3: " << sec3 << "\n"
            << "end flag: " << sizeof(MAGIC_END) << "\n"
            << "sum: " << 8 + sec1 + sec2 + sec3 + sizeof(MAGIC_END) << "\n\n";

        return result;
    }

    static GribData loadDataFromFile(const std::string& path) {
        std::ifstream file(path, std::ios::binary);

        ByteVec data;
        std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
            {},
            std::back_inserter(data));

        return loadData(data);
    }
};


int main() {
    auto grib = GribData::loadDataFromFile("message_2_G1.grib");
    grib.print();
}
```

Here is expected result, as I have copied it from console

```
size: 4538
sec0: 8
sec1: 28
sec2: 178
sec3: 4320
end flag: 4
sum: 4538

### Section IS ###
magicFlag: 1196575042
size: 1191186874
edition: 1

### Section PDS ###
size: 28
tableVersion: 2
indentificatorOfCenter: 7
numProcessID: 81
gridIndentification: 37
flagForGDSorBMS: 128
indParamAndUnit: 33
indTypeOfLevelOrLayer: 100
levelOrLayer: 850
year: 15
month: 3
day: 10
hour: 0
minute: 0
forecastTimeUnit: 1
p1: 0
p2: 0
indTimeRange: 10
averageOrAccumulate: 0
missing: 0
century: 21
subcenterId: 0
decimalScale: 1
```

Comment: Note that using a union for type-punning like you do with `buffer` in the `getReverseEndianValue` function is invalid in C++. It will probably do the right thing, but technically you can only read from the last written-to member of a union, writing to a member and then reading from another is [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Also, take for example `getReverseEndianValue<uint32_t, 3>(iter)`. Here you tell the function `getReverseEndianValue` that the size of the data is three bytes, which means that the union member `tmp` will be three bytes. But `uint32_t` is *four* bytes. So you will go out of bounds of the array, leading to another case of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: At which place does the program crash when run in a debugger?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude since OP is using GCC it's not true that type-punning is undefined behaviour. It's defined by GCC. Saying it's undefined _in general_ would be true, but not necessarily relevant to this question. (Writing three bytes then reading four is still a problem, unless the fourth byte was safely initialized first to a meaningful default value).

Comment: I've tested a little bit on the file you linked, but not got it to crash. I suspect that the cause is the fact that you write only 3 bytes to the union, but then  read 4 out from it. Since you don't initialize it to 0 to begin with, you might sometimes be getting some invalid values in the one byte you don't set. 

As a fix for the undefined behaviour, you should just default initialize a T value, then reinterpret_cast it as char* and copy the bytes into that. 

Also, write the size, sec1 etc values as soon as you have them so it's easier to debug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, it's not very useful to use `g++ main.cpp -pedantic` because you haven't enabled any warnings. Add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compiler flags, and also `-g` so you can debug it.

Compiling with `-fsanitize=undefined` shows a runtime error caused by using a null pointer where a valid pointer is needed:

```
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:368:23: runtime error: null pointer passed as argument 2, which is declared to never be null
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This means your program has a bug.

Compiling with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` will add additional checks to `std::vector` and that tells you the problem:

```
/usr/include/c++/8/debug/safe_iterator.h:374:
Error: attempt to advance a past-the-end iterator 4 steps, which falls 
outside its valid range.

Objects involved in the operation:
    iterator @ 0x0x7fffb09ceb90 {
      type = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char const*, std::__cxx1998::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, std::__debug::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > > (constant iterator);
      state = past-the-end;
      references sequence with type 'std::__debug::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >' @ 0x0x7fffb09cf050
    }
Aborted (core dumped)
```

You should run the program under a debugger to see where this invalid iterator increment happens. Running the program in GDB and then using its `up` command to move up the stack shows the error comes from here, in `loadData`:

```
    constexpr char MAGIC_START[4] = { 'G', 'R', 'I', 'B' };
    constexpr char MAGIC_END[4] = { '7', '7', '7', '7' };

    auto start = std::search(rawdata.cbegin(),
        rawdata.cend(),
        std::begin(MAGIC_START),
        std::end(MAGIC_START));

    auto end = std::search(rawdata.cbegin(),
        rawdata.cend(),
        std::begin(MAGIC_END),
        std::end(MAGIC_END));

    ByteVec data(start, end + sizeof(MAGIC_END));
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Consider what happens when `rawdata` does not contain the `MAGIC_START` characters, but does contain the `MAGIC_END` characters. Will `start` and `end` form a valid iterator range?

Consider what happens when `rawdata` does not contain the `MAGIC_END` characters. Will `end + sizeof(MAGIC_END)` be valid?

You should not assume the two calls to `std::search` work as expected. You should add some error checking, by testing whether `start == rawdata.end()` or `end == rawdata.end()`. If either of those is true, something has gone wrong (probably bad input in the `rawdata` string).

You should also learn how to use a debugger, and learn about the additional tools your compiler provides for detecting bugs (e.g. GCC's  `-fsanitize=undefined` and `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` options should be used to help confirm the presence of bugs, and GDB should be used to find where those bugs happen).

Comment: Hey @Jonathan, your explanation about proper use of g++ came in handy, thank you for that.
Also thank you for wide explanation with most of the issues explained.

Thanks to it i was able to fix the bugs so the program doesn't crash anymore and outputs correctly.